# Error when opening csv file on micropython (Raspberry Pi Pico)

Tags: csv, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

So this is my code; I have both my python file and csv file in my raspberry pi pico already. However, when I run it, it returns an error. I've already imported the sys module as others recommended, unfortunately, the issue still remain present.

```
#from machine import Pin, I2c
#from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
#import framebuff
import time
from sys import stdin

w = 128
h= 32

#oled = I2C(0,scl=Pin(1),)

df = []
delim = ','
with open('colordata.csv','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        df.append(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r').split(delim))

def color_recognition(r,g,b):
    color = 'Unknown'
    names =[]
    index = []
    threshold = 50
    for i in range(len(df)):
        R = int(df[i][4])
        G = int(df[i][5])
        B = int(df[i][6])
        diff = abs(r - R) + abs(g -G) + abs(b-B)
        if diff <= threshold:
            index.append(diff)
            names.append(df[i][2])
    
    
    if len(index)>0:
        result = sorted(index)[0]
        for j in range(len(index)):
            if index[j]==result:
                color = names[j]
    else:
        pass
        

    return color
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 4096 bytes
PROBLEM IN THONNY'S BACK-END: Exception while handling 'Run' (thonny.plugins.micropython.mp_back.ManagementError: Command output was not empty).
See Thonny's backend.log for more info.
You may need to press "Stop/Restart" or hard-reset your MicroPython device and try again.


Process ended with exit code 1.
```

What can I do to fix this calamity? Should I change interpreter? Additional info: the data contains 864 rows and 6 columns.

Comment: The Pico only has [about 192kB of RAM free](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=11037), so it seems likely you're simply running out of memory. The first thing to observe is that you're repeatedly appending to `df`, which will cause multiple memory allocations, but i think you'll also need to think about how you can store the data you're putting into `df` in a more compact way.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering, MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 4096 bytes, indicates that there is not enough memory available on your Raspberry Pi Pico to execute the program. The Pico has limited resources, and handling large datasets may lead to memory constraints.

In my opinion I actually think that your dataset is too large to load in a single instance for the pico's computing power. I prefer that you read the file line by line instead of loading the entire CSV file in the pico's memory.

```
with open('colordata.csv', 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    data = line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r').split(delim)
```

Also try using external storage if possible and check if it helps.